# Performance issue for automation application

Tags: java, automation, pcf

I have created an API in spring boot which internally uses RestAssured to call other API for APIAutomation application.

When one person hits the API it works fine but when two persons hit the API then out of two, one gets success and other gets failure with the output mixed up.

Comment: we need more than that to be able to help you

Comment: can you share the response you receive from the api?